# gdalUtils in R not linking to rgdal install

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

I am currently running `R 3.4.4` through Rstudio on a windows system. I have a code that I ran successfully several months ago, but now it seems my `gdalUtils` is unable to connect with my `rgdal` install. Any function I call receives the following error:

```
Probably broken install of `gdal` at 'C:/PROGRA~2/GDAL/'
Error in as.Date.default(unlist(versions)) : 
do not know how to convert `unlist(versions)` to class “`Date`”
```

I've tried searching for the `gdal` install within the `rgdal` package and get the same error.   I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything to no avail. Any advice would be appreciated!
A

Comment: Solved it...  I had a rogue version of gdal installed.   I uninstalled it and R was able to link to rgdal correctly.  Not sure how to override that default (I tried gdal_setInstallation with no luck), but solved for now.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I had 2 installs of GDAL: the one that comes with QGis and another one I had before. I uninstalled the second one, and the problem got solved. Thanks,  @ame0707 !